# Make children span/div take 100% width and auto height for parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a couple of spans inside of a div, what I want to know is how I can get the spans to take up 100% width of the parent div but the height of these spans should be auto.
CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 90;
    background: #4070da;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.parent span{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>Depart</span>
  <span>07</span>
  <span>Mar 2018</span>
</div>
```

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: Date Image]

Comment: Please note that `className` is not a valid HTML property name. You are probably using jsx here, nonetheless you should take care to adjust that if you show code here that is supposed to be HTML.

Comment: @connexo sorry for the trouble, I have edited the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a normal way to do this and drop your flex box approach:

```css
.parent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 90;
    background: #4070da;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.parent span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>Depart</span>
  <span>07</span>
  <span>Mar 2018</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
My understanding of your question is that you want to centre the text that appears  in Span elements around the width of the DIV

**Solution**
I have altered spans to DIVs as they are more easier to control than spans and given them classes so that you control styling.

**Example Output**
The example doesnt reflect your image as it takes into account you want the text to be proportionate to the parent element, in this case I have set to the element to be deliberately at 200px to the right to show that even when doing so, the text remains proportionate to its parent element.

However, to get the exact same as you demonstrated just alter width: 200px to 100%; under the parent css class.

```css
.parent {
    background: #4070da;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
}
.text{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(200px / 3);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0:auto;
  font-family: "arial";
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2.6; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">Depart</div>
  <div class="text">07</div>
  <div class="text">Mar 2018</div>
</div>
```